# How to reach a variable or something from onCreate?

Tags: android

Im new at android developing. I want to use the returning value of "mean" and than displaying as a string, but I cant reach it from onCreate and I dont know how to do that. Here is the code:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8 ,9, 10};

public static double mean(double[] x) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        sum += x[i];
    }
    return sum / x.length;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = double.toString(mean);


    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);
}
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: String message = Double.toString(mean(x));

Comment: right @blackbelt, also make x a double[], or change function mean() to expect an int[]

Comment: @blackbelt Double.toString()

Comment: @m0skit0 one of many (erros)

Comment: You should also call setContentView once. The first call you do is replaced by the second one.

Comment: Work like charm! Big thx to all for helping me out, and sorry for the noob question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I cant reach it from onCreate and I dont know how to do that.

You *can* reach it. You just didn't pass in the double array as an argument.